# How to implement advance search functionalities in spring boot and mongoDb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to implement a api endpoint made with spring boot and mongoDB as database. it accepts name as a paramter and it should follow fuzzy search logic. Suppose we have a data in our database, flipkart should get searched when we search with a wrong spelling flipcart.
Fuzzy Search logic follows:

1. All words from the search query should be available in the "name" attribute, in any order.
2. The search should tolerate small spelling mistakes.

One more example
domino cheese pizza should get searched if I search for pizza domeno

I tried all the queries but I wasnt able to do it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.